# TOMCAT - catalina.properties - custom variables

Tags: tomcat

in TOMCAT catalina.properties it's possible the definition of custom vars:

```
myLib = D:/proj/library
```

but if I define another var using the previous, isn't working:

```
myLibDir = ${myLib}/dir
```

myLibDir isn't resolved, as I expected, with **D:/proj/library/dir**
but with the string **'${myLib}/dir'**

How to define a var using antoher ???

Comment: I think ```${variable}``` is for Unix only. Have you attempted ```%variable``` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One of the way is using property files.

(e.g) You can define following properties on **catalina.properties**

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=com.abc.ExternalPropertySource
com.abc.ExternalPropertySource.file=abc-enterprise.properties
```

Create a file with the name `abc-enterprise.properties` on Tomcat\conf folder and define the list of properties

```
SslPassword=P@ssw0rd
```

You can call this property by specifying `${SslPassword}` on both Linux & Windows.

One of our project we have specified keystore password  as like above on server.xml.

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol" 
           port="8090" minSpareThreads="64" maxThreads="512"
    sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
    enableLookups="false" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" tcpNoDelay="true" compression="force" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/x-java-applet,application/octet-stream,application/xml,text/javascript,text/css,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/gif,application/pdf,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/x-shockwave-flash,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml+xhtml" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" server="MY Manager">


    <SSLHostConfig ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" certificateVerification="none" protocols="TLSv1.2" sslProtocol="TLS"><Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="webapps/myManager.bin" certificateKeyAlias="myAlias" certificateKeystorePassword="${SslPassword}" /></SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for replies but the problem is
when I define, in Catalina.properties a new var using another.

in Catalina.properties I have:

```
myLib = D:/proj/library
myLibDir=${myLib}/myDir
```

then using ${myLib} in web.xml is okay, the var is correctly resolved with the string **D:/proj/library** but wiht ${myLibdir} the result is not as expected **D:/proj/library/MyDir** but **${myLib}/myDir**.

This is strange because in Catalina.properties there's is, for example:

```
commons.loader="${catalina.base}/lib,..."
```

and that's exactly what I need...

but it's seem not working with new variables.